# foreignObject render text outside SVG border

Tags: reactjs, svg, foreignobject

here is my full case I need to draw Hexagon with text in the middle of it.
this working just nice on Chrome Mac, but on safari, it renders outside border

```
 <Hexagon style={{ stroke: "white", fill: "#A1A1A1" }} flatTop>
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
      <Typography
        variant="subtitle1"
        gutterBottom
        className={classes.hexTitleStyle}
      >
        First Line
        <br />
        Second Line
      </Typography>
    </foreignObject>
  </Hexagon>
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj296ymvyj)

how its render on Chrome Mac 
[image]

how its render on Safari Mac 
[image]

Comment: report a [webkit bug](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: note that `width=percentage` is an SVG2 feature. Not sure that Safari supports it currently.

Comment: What if you try using the <text> tag instead?

Comment: <text> tag could be great but how can I center and wrap text